# getting response from server

Tags: android, sockets

i want to communicate with emulator and pc.i am using emulator as a client and pc as server.i am sending data from emulator to pc properly but i am unable to get the response of the server i.e pc.can u plz help me in this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need proxy between emulator interface and your pc. Try to forward ports ([link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#forwardports)):

```
adb forward tcp:8888 tcp:8888
```